# in oracle apex need to hide items on page load depend on select values from DB

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

```
select column_name , column_default_value from columns_setting_table;
```

result

```
  -- column_name -- -- column_default_value --
     branch_name    ,   head_q
     cost_Center    ,   Cost01
```

so in apex form will display 2 items and set label for each one

- first `branch_name`
- second `cost_Center`
- third *hidden* because no value came from statement

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Can you please explain it clearly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you are doing here, but - to hide an item, you'd use **Server condition** property. For example, if you pick a *function that returns Boolean*:

```
return :P1.THIRD_ITEM is not null;
```

Or, if you pick *Item is not null*, put just

```
P1.THIRD_ITEM
```

in there.